# "Is not being" vs. "has not being"

Tags: passive-voice, present-vs-perfect

> - BBC channel is not being broadcast in our area for a year ago.
> - BBC channel has not being broadcasted in our area for a year ago.

Which one is grammatical? Depending upon time span I think number two is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5):

Both are incorrect. If you want to say that BBC hasn't broadcast anything for a year in your area, you can say:

> BBC World hasn't broadcast anything in our area for a year.

If it's an ongoing situation and you want to describe its state, you can say:

> BBC World is not being broadcast in our area.

If it's a past thing, you can say:

> BBC World stopped broadcasting in our area a year ago.

Comment: Noah, so "is not being broadcast" is a situation whose end is uncertain even if possible?

Comment: What "is not being broadcast" is saying is that there is no broadcast at present.  It makes no further assertion of any kind.

Comment: +0.5 OP asks about passive forms; I think you need to offer both active and passive versions of all three.